# How to acces the second value

Tags: php, html

I was wondering if you could give two values ​​to a class and then acces to the second one by POST, something like this (part of the code):

```
      echo "<select name='selecttsk' id='selecttsk'>";                 
while($w = $bd->obtener_fila($tasker, 0)){
     echo "<option class='opcion1' value ='".$w[1]/$w[2]."'>".$w[0]."</option>";

}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

and then i need to do something like this in other file

```
$var = $_POST[selecttsk];
```

but i need $w[2]

thanks

Comment: Is this not working in some way?  As long as the code on the first page runs without error and emits valid HTML, the form value will be posted to the second page like any other.

Comment: Please note that the question title is not where you throw in tags such as `[html]` and `[php]`; you have already done this in the proper place. That leaves "double value", which is not really a question.

Comment: As @David said, you need to explain what is not working for us to help. Once the user submits the form, the value of the drop-down list is flattened into plain-text, and the PHP $_POST[] has no idea of the difference between $w[1] and $w[2] (it's all just one string at that point). One option is to temporary change your submit method to get (instead of post), and then see what value appears in your URL (after the submit). That might help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your $_POST['selecttsk'] does have the values in the following format:

"foo/bar"

You could use "explode" in PHP to get the second part (bar), for example:

```php
$postvar = $_POST['selecttsk'];
$vars = explode("/", $postvar);
// Then
$var = $vars[1]; // Will be the $w[2] from the form
```

Look into: http://php.net/explode

Beware that if $w[1] or $w[2] ever contains a "/" you might get unexpected results, you could use the limit function of explode to mitigate that issue.

However - I would generally not recommend this workflow.
Why do you need to send two variables with one select? 
(could you show us som example of what $w contains)